# Java, making bank accounts based off file

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

For a homework assignment I need to read a file in this format:

```
Miller
William
00001
891692 06 <--this is supposed to be the dollar amount in the account
```

I need to find a way to split after every dollar amount, which is every 4 lines.

Comment: Can't you just read the file line by line and assume every 4th line is the dollar amount of the account?

Comment: Also use `new Scanner(new File());` And make sure you skip blank lines!

Comment: I just removed the homework tag - please note there's a huge push on SO at the moment to remove this tag, so please don't use it on new questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerEx {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    int count = 1;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
        if(count % 4 == 0) {
             //Dollar amount in nextLine
        }
        count++;
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `BufferedReader` to read the file contents while maintaining a `lineCount`, for each line. then use `String.split` on every 4th line:

```
if (lineCount % 4 == 0) {
   String[] dollarAmount = String.split(" ");
}
...
```